# Trying to write script, that would download all subfolders inside folder

Tags: python, tcp

so I'm here again with my handsome script, that should download data from *my* second computer using TCP sockets. I've got a couple of questions, that I was not able to find on google.

**Question n.1:**
First of all, is there a way, to check if a string is ending without extension? I found, that I can use `.endswith()`, but it doesn't work the way I would like to, because I would have to define every extension that exists in the World, and that wouldn't be so practical.

**EDIT: I just found the solution for that second question, right away when I was reading this post.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with filenames in a cross-platform way, you should use the `os` module.
Getting the extension from a filename is supported by the `os.path.splitext` function:

```
# '.file' extension
filepath = "this/is/a.file"
_, ext = os.path.splitext(filepath)
print(len(ext))

# No extension
filepath = "this/is/afile"
_, ext = os.path.splitext(filepath)
print(len(ext))
```

will output:

```
5
0
```

`5` for the extension of `.file` and `0` for there not being an extension. Thus you can check if a filename has an extension with a function like:

```
def has_ext(filepath):
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(filepath)
    return len(ext) > 0
```

Comment: Ahh, I did not read the function of `os.path.splitext()` properly. Thanks for reminding me!